# How to use bash script to sum a column base on the condition of another column and deal with exception?

Tags: bash, shell

Say my file is:

```
1  pretty_    18
2  _candy123  2
3  kitty      9
4  hellokitty 11
```

I want to sum the $3 column if $2 column contains "ty"; since $2 is the only column that contains letters, I want to use:

```
grep "ty" output | awk '{sum+=$3} END{print sum}'
```

My questions are:

1. What should I do if the file has another column that may contain "ty"(the calculation should only be based on $2)?
2. What should I add if I want to output 0 when there is no "ty" in all the second columns?

Thank you!

Comment: Given the input above, is the desired output sum 40 or 38?  That is, so you wish _all_ of $3 summed if _any_ of $2 contains `ty`, or only those lines of $3 that are next to `ty`, (which would exclude line #2).

Answer (score 1):

You can add an condition to each block, for example `awk 'NR > 2{print $2}' file`

`~` allows to match variable with regex

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /ty/{sum+=$3} END{print sum}' output
38
```

If pattern is not found even once, different ways to handle:

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /abc/{sum+=$3} END{print sum}' output

$ awk '$2 ~ /abc/{sum+=$3} END{print sum+0}' output
0
$ awk '$2 ~ /abc/{sum+=$3} END{print +sum}' output
0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
x=($(cut -d ' ' -f3 FILE|grep -n ty|cut -d ':' -f1|paste -d $'\t' - - -))

for i in ${x[@]}
do
    nl -n ln FILE|grep ^$i|tr $'\t' ' '|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2,4|tr ' ' '+'|bc
done
```